# select single attribute value from multiple with condition query type xml in XUL tree

Tags: xpath, tree, xul, xquery

This is my xml file: Need in help in write proper xpath expression using query type xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65539</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>Arun_niit</FirstName>
<LastName>Arun_niit</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="yahoo" Value="nura_e@yahoo.co.in"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65553</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>GhorbelMahmoud</FirstName>
<LastName>Mahmoud Ghorbel</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="alcatel-lucent" Value="mahmoud.gbel@alcatel-lucent.com"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65560</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>keyankarthik</FirstName>
<LastName>karthik keyan</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="yahoo" Value="kartse@yahoo.co.in"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65567</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>Rangarajkarthik</FirstName>
<LastName>karthik Rangaraj</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="gmail" Value="kart2006@gmail.com"/>
<EMail Domain="yahoo" Value="karthikngaraj@yahoo.com"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65576</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>ReddyAkky</FirstName>
<LastName>Akky Reddy</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="gmail" Value="akkddych@gmail.com"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65597</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>KumarVeera</FirstName>
<LastName>Veera_Kumar</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="yahoo" Value="KUMRg_81@yahoo.com"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

My xul tree:

```
<treechildren datasources="file://D:/xmlparserinxul/finalxmlonfriday.xml" ref="*" querytype="xml">
   <template>
     <query expr="CONTACT">
       <assign var="?pde" expr="PDE-Identity"/>
       <assign var="?fname" expr="FirstName"/>
       <assign var="?lname" expr="LastName"/>
       <assign var="?gmail" expr="EMAILS/EMail/@Domain='gmail'|EMail/@Value"/>
       <assign var="?yahoo" expr="EMAILS/EMail/@Domain='yahoo'|EMail/@Value"/>
       <assign var="?alcatel-lucent" expr="EMAILS/EMail/@Domain='alcatel-lucent'|EMail/@Value"/>
       <assign var="?facebook" expr="URL"/>
       <assign var="?id" expr="Facebook-ID"/>
    </query>
     <action>
       <treeitem uri="?">
         <treerow>
           <treecell label="?pde"/>
           <treecell label="?fname"/>
           <treecell label="?lname"/>
           <treecell label="?gmail"/>
           <treecell label="?yahoo"/>
           <treecell label="?alcatel-lucent"/>
           <treecell label="?facebook" editable="false"/>
           <treecell label="?id" editable="false"/>
         </treerow>
       </treeitem>
     </action>
   </template>
 </treechildren>

 </tree>
```

I couldn't write proper query to talk the email values according to the domain. Some one please help me...I have edited the previous question here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is using XML templates and have the tree contents generated automatically, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Template_Guide/XML_Templates and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Template_Guide/XML_Assignments. In your case it would work like this:

```
 <treechildren datasources="file:///D:/FinalXMl.xml" ref="*" querytype="xml">
   <template>
     <query expr="CONTACT">
       <assign var="?fname" expr="FirstName"/>
       <assign var="?lname" expr="LastName"/>
       <assign var="?gmail" expr="EMAILS/EMail[Type='gmail']/Value"/>
       <assign var="?yahoo" expr="EMAILS/EMail[Type='yahoo']/Value"/>
       <assign var="?facebook" expr="Facebook-ID"/>
     </query>
     <action>
       <treeitem uri="?">
         <treerow>
           <treecell label="?fname"/>
           <treecell label="?lname"/>
           <treecell label="?gmail"/>
           <treecell label="?yahoo"/>
           <treecell label=""/>
           <treecell label="?facebook"/>
         </treerow>
       </treeitem>
     </action>
   </template>
 </treechildren>
```

Note that this would be easier (`<assign>` tags unnecessary) if you could change your XML format. If you put all the data into attributes of the `<CONTACT>` tags you can access it without explicitly assigning variables.

It seems that you want to implement dynamic filtering of the tree eventually, this should work by changing the `expr` attribute of the `<query>` tag dynamically. You can use any XPath expression, e.g. `expr="CONTACT[FirstName='Bob']"` will only select contacts with `FirstName` child having the value `Bob`.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Everything is working fine. could please give me some more information about filter. [code]<hbox align="center" id="search-box">
        <label accesskey="F" control="filter">Filter</label>
        <textbox id="filter" oncommand="SearchKeyword(this)" flex="1"/>
        <button id="clearFilter" oncommand="clearFilter()" label="Clear" accesskey="C" disabled="true"/>
    </hbox> [/code] . Here i have textbox which allows me to type something to extract. So, do i have to use xpath query in Javascript? Please give some information for this and sort. Thank you.

Comment: @karthikin: You should google XPath expressions. From a quick glance, these seem to be passable introductions: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/xml/xpath-151-retrieving-nodes-from-an-xml-document and http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html. Give the `<query>` tag an ID attribute and do `document.getElementById("...").setAttribute("expr", "CONTACT[...]")`

Comment: Got it. You know we can edit the tree cell like this" <tree editable="true" id="tree" flex="1"> " this allows to edit in the table. I would like to know if we edit something in the table and how we can update the edited information into the xml file(Edit/save dynamically). Thank U.

Comment: @karthikin: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087697/capture-editable-tree-changes-in-xul/6252142#6252142

Comment: @Wladimir: It'a a very good inforamtion thank u but in our case we have loaded the tree dynamically using xpath query from xml file. In tree we have editable="true" which we can edit statically but it wont update/reflect in the xml file. How we can do this? Thank U.

Comment: @karthikin: Both using `DOMAttrModified` event handler and wrapping `nsITreeView` should work here as well. But you will have to save the changes manually, there is no way to have it happen automatically.

Comment: @Wladimir: could you please tell me do i have to write the query for filter in javascript function or inside the template. Thanks

Comment: @Wladimir: still i couldn't fix the filter problem.  Could you please help me to fix this problem. I have assigned the query dynamically buy still it's not working. Thank you.

Comment: <CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65567</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>Rangarajkarthik</FirstName>
<LastName>karthik Rangaraj</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<EMAILS>
<EMail Domain="gmail" Value="kart2006@gmail.com"/>
<EMail Domain="yahoo" Value="karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com"/>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>     need query to get the email value from xml. <assign var="?gmail" expr="EMAILS/EMail[@Domain='gmail']"/>   Thank u.